# Convert String to bigram list

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to learn haskell and I need you help in something that it may be simple but I'm not being able to resolve.

I have a string:

```
ABCDEFG
```

I need to convert this string to this format:

```
A-B
B-C
C-D
D-E
E-F
F-G
```

Is someone kind enough to give me some tips?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `zip` from `Data.List` like this :

```
let str = "ABCDEFG"
in zip str $ tail str
```

which returns a list of pairs `[(Char, Char)]`.

Then to output something like in your question, you could do something like this :

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let str     = "ABCDEFGH"
      couples = zip str $ tail str
  mapM_ (\(x,y) -> putStrLn $ x : '-' : y : "") couples
```

Comment: ...which can be compressed even further to `zipWithM_ (\x y -> putStrLn $ [x,'-',y]) str (tail str)`.

Comment: This is really strange code for me, but... wow :) I'll have to study this functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can pair successive characters using `zip` and `drop`:

```
let str = "ABCDEFG"
let pairs = zip str (drop 1 str)
```

then you can map over the list of character pairs to create the string:

```
map (\(f, s) -> f:'-':s:[]) pairs
```

which gives you a list of strings.

As the comment points out, instead of `zip`, `map` and `drop 1` you could use `zipWith` and `tail`:

```
zipWith (\f s -> f:'-':s:[]) str (tail str)
```

You can do this in a single line:

```
let stringList = map (\(f, s) -> f:'-':s:[]) $ zip str (drop 1 str)
```

If you need a single output string you can use `unlines` e.g.

```
let str = unlines stringList
```

As a single function:

```
formatPairs :: String -> String
formatPairs str = unlines $ map (\(f, s) -> f:'-':s:[]) $ zip str (drop 1 str)
```

or

```
formatPairs :: String -> String
formatPairs str = unlines $ zipWith (\f s -> f:'-':s:[]) str (tail str)
```

If you need to print it you can use `putStr`:

```
putStr (formatPairs "ABCDEFG")
```